# I have problem with assets in flutter web on ngnix server

Tags: flutter, nginx

I release flutter app
And when I run it locally (with pyhton server) it works well
but when I put it on server (I have problem with images)
this is my ngnix config

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name X www.X.ir X.ir;

        location / {
            root /var/www/html/secret_hitler/web;
            index index.html;
        }
    }
}
```

every thing seems well except images

I tried
try_files $uri /index.html;
copy icon folder
copy whole assets folder
but what is interesting for me is that no only do not show inages but also not try to get them in network

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look to your access and error log file located here :

- /var/log/nginx/error.log
- /var/log/nginx/access.log

I think the mistake come from the "location /" part, you need to set your root folder in the server block and not inside the "location /" block.

Edit your nginx config as follow :

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name X www.X.ir X.ir;
  root /var/www/html/secret_hitler/web;
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
}
```